# how to work http header in cordova android?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, http-headers, ionic-framework

I am using the below method to call web service having basic authentication:

```
var url = 'http:sampleurl' + Username;
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(Username + ':' + password);
var session = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(Username + ':' + password);
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        cookie: session
    }
}).
success(function(data, status) {
    window.localStorage['userdata'] = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $cookies.logged = 'success';
    window.localStorage['uname'] = Username;
    window.localStorage['pass'] = password;
    $scope.loginData = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };
    $state.go('app.tasklists');
}).
```

This method working fine in ios platform of ionic app, but it is not working in android platform. In android platform header is not able to clear after a successful login. If i use a wrong password or different user the server return the first logged in user details.

Answer (score -1):

Because you forgot to put `;` instead `.` at the of function .

Comment: Thanks,Where i need to change .in http function?it is default method

Comment: at the end of your function. the success function.

Comment: Thanks,but after success function i have error(function(data, status, headers, config) {


      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Info!',
       template: 'Invalid Password, or no user found with this Email Address'
      });

      return false;

     });